# How to add jquery to asp.net page and format gridview columns

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have seen multiple articles/questions about formatting a gridview rows using jquery.
However consider this my first attempt to write a jquery and use it in an asp.net page.

I manage to do the following, but it doesn't do anything to the gridview. What have I done wrong?

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
</head>
```

Within body section, after GridView1 is created:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> td:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#FFCCCC");
    $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> td:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#99CCFF");
});
</script>
```

I also have this jquery saved as jqueryColumnColours.js in the scripts folder. So the second question, how can I use .js file without really writing the above function within aspx page?

EDIT:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#GridView1 td:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#FFCCCC");
            $("#GridView1 td:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#99CCFF");
        });
```

Comment: Always use latest jquery plugin from http://jquery.com/ and no need to write <% %> in jquery for selecting an element .. just use $("#Gridview1 td:nth-child(odd)")...it is enuf!!!

Comment: @Aj_sari still no luck. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the latest jquery like:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and add the script tag just before closing body section,

```
        </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#grid td:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "Tan");

    </script>
</body>
```

I hope it helps!!!

---

**EDIT** by bonCodigo:
The only change that works for my page was having `http://` instead of `//`

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: In the scripts folder I don't see the latest jQuery version though. Could that be a problem? Anyway I have declared exactly as you have stated. But no luck at all.... Although it's only one GridView in the page - I am using another Gridview in c# code to group this physical gridview's headers.

Comment: Update ur <script src="bla..blah"> </script> with mine

Comment: With `"//ajax` it says the file is not found. So I put single `/` Still the same...output

Comment: It is hosted jquery file it is on cloud ...no need to change anything it works...jus keep as it is...

Comment: You know I found the issue.. ;) `<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ` That means... the `//` is infact `http://` But I am accepting yours. Secondly this doesn't colour the entire gridview. The sub headers are left uncoloured... Any possibility to colour only a one set of columns and not all. Lets say starting from column index 3 to last: all odds and all evens.

Comment: Glad it could help u!! Just try to learn basics of how to integrate jquery from jquery site.....!!! U have to add the correct path to src

Comment: Check this it could help u https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child